# discord.py - ' json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) ' error when trying to make a leveling system

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a leveling system for my bot. Since I don't know how to make one, I searched on the internet to find a basic one. I found this: [How to create a leveling system with discord.py with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62042331/how-to-create-a-leveling-system-with-discord-py-with-python)
I decided to try this code out to see if it would work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65160683/22771345
When i tried the command, I made the level.json file and all it did was give me this: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`
I've tried doing everything to fix this issue, but it just gave me the exact. same. error. I have tried json.loads([thinger]), and it also didnt work. I even tried this: [JSON Error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55766785/json-error-json-decoder-jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char) and it also didnt help me with my problem. Does anyone know how to fix this? Please and thank you!

Code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        print('function load')
        with open('level.json','r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
            print('file load')
        await update_data(users, message.author,message.guild)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 4, message.guild)
        await level_up(users, message.author,message.channel, message.guild)

        with open('level.json','w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
    await bot.process_commands(message)




async def update_data(users, user,server):
    if not str(server.id) in users:
        users[str(server.id)] = {}
        if not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1
    elif not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp, server):
  users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel, server):
  experience = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']
  lvl_start = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
  lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))
  if str(user.guild.id) != '757383943116030074':
    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
      await channel.send('{} has leveled up to Level {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
      users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = lvl_end


@bot.command(aliases = ['rank','lvl'])
async def level(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):

    if not member:
        user = ctx.message.author
        with open('level.json','r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
        exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']

        embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {}'.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP " ,color = discord.Color.green())
        embed.set_author(name = ctx.author, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    else:
      with open('level.json','r') as f:
          users = json.load(f)
      lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['level']
      exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['experience']
      embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {}'.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP" ,color = discord.Color.green())
      embed.set_author(name = member, icon_url = member.avatar_url)

      await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Comment: Please include the traceback message so that we see the failing line. And try to make a smaller example focused just on the error. It doesn't matter what your code does after the error, so you can remove it.

Comment: That error means that json tried to decode a zero-length string. That's what the weird "expecting value a 0" thing is all about. Likely `level.json` is empty. So the question may be how it got that way. But the other question is how you want your code to handle the condition?

Comment: _level.json IS empty_ Then it isn't a valid json file.  That's the problem.

Comment: As a note, you do several awaits between reading and writing the file. Other things could potentially run and read / write that same file. And that will loose data because you end up writing old stale stuff.

Comment: I can confirm that level.json IS empty, but what should I put there so it wouldn't error? edit: I found the experience and level, but I have no idea where I should put it as

Comment: Not sure... is it a dict of users? You could catch the JSONDecodeError and assign `users = {}`. Now you have a users database with no users and hopefully your other code does the right thing.

Comment: I've tried that, and it didnt work. I found the causing error where it was causing from: ```users = json.load(f)```